DSA known messages related random key
We know the $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}, h_{1}, h_{2}, q, s_{1}, s_{2}$ also $k_{2} = k_{1} \mod q$. Trying to find $a$, I get
$$s_{1} = k^{-1}(h_{1} + a \times r_{1}) \mod q$$
and
$$s_{2} = (2k)^{-1} \times (h_{2} + a \times r_{2}) \mod q.$$
Can't we rearrange them like $s_{1} \times s_{2}^{-1} \times 2^{-1} \times (h_{2} + a \times r_{2}) = h_{1} + a \times r_{1} \mod q$?
Calling $c = s_{1} \times s_{2}^{-1} \times 2^{-1}$, don't we get $(h_{2} + a \times r_{2}) \times c = (h_{1} + a \times r_{1}) \mod q$. This means that
$$c\times h_{2} - h_{1} = a\times (r_{1} - c \times r_{2}) \mod q$$
$$\Rightarrow a = (c \times h_{2} - h_{1}) \times (r_{1} -c \times r_{2})^{-1} \mod q.$$
But when I try to find the inverse of $r_{1} - c \times r_{2}$ the algorithm finds none, and I know it works correctly, where is the miscalculation here?
